# Trying to use command line ls -l argument as scanf input

Tags: c, shell, scanf

I'm trying to parse through the ls -l output to check file permission and size. However it seems that the scanf() function does not take in anything after a space. Is there any trick or workaround for this? I'd like to stick to using scanf but if it's not possible then I'm open to suggestions. When I run the program below and print test2 only "total" gets stored.

```
<#include stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

char test[200];
char test2[200];
scanf("%c\n", test);
for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++){
    if(test[i] != '\n'){
       test2[i] = test[i];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    printf("%c\n", test2[i]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Thanks. Also is there a way to check if something is a file or a directory from just using ls -l?

Comment: @FiddlingBits why don't you say something relevant to the question?

Comment: @FiddlingBits he was clearly open to using another function rather than relying on fscan. not discarding the program all together.

Comment: Reading the output of `ls -l` is not a good idea. It makes the code tightly coupled with the `ls` output format which can be spoofed via `sed` or `tr`. I suggest you use `stat()`.

Comment: when callling scanf() and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Since you want scanf() to read until a '\n' is encountered you might use: `scanf( " %199[^\n]", test);`  Which will 1) skip over leading white space, 2) read the input stream into 'test' until a '\n' is encountered or 199 characters are read.  Then append a '\0' character to the characters in 'test' making the contents of 'test' a valid character string.

Comment: the call to scanf() will probably need to be in a loop so it can read all the input, line by line

Comment: @user3629249 Would it be better to store everything read from that scanf you provided into one single character array and then the newline (not sure if it would be put in the array) character should indicate the next line right?

Answer (score 1):

> However it seems that the scanf() function does not take in anything after a space. ... `scanf("%c\n", test);`

It is not `scanf()`, it is the format used.  `scanf("%c\n", test);` scans 1 `char` into `test` (test is not necessarily null character terminated) and then scans and tosses any white-space.  It continues to do so until non-white-space is found.

More likely you want `scanf(" %199[^\n]", test); fgetc(stdin);` which will 1) scan and discard white-space, 2) scan up to 199 non-`'\n'`.  3) stop when full, EOF, or `'\n'` detected.  Then the next character is scanned and tossed.

In general. best to use `fgets()`

```
if (fgets(test, sizeof test, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
test[strcspn(test, "\n")] = 0;  // lop off potential \n.

for (size_t i = 0; test[i]; i++){
  printf("%c\n", test[i]);
}
```

To be clear, it is not that `scanf()` is evil, it is just trying to to do many things (IO and conversions).  Better to separate.

Most `scanf()` format specifiers and directive `' '` do not distinguish between space and `'\n'`.  That line ending is critical to your code.  `fgets()` seeks for an `'\n'` and treats spaces like any other `char`.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks. Also is there a way to check if something is a file or a directory from just using ls -l?*

the first line starts with 'total' and can be discarded.

Each following line (use fgets() to read each line) 
begins with the 'permissions'

The very first char of the permissions indicates what type of file:

```
'd' directory, 
'c' character oriented device, 
'b' block oriented device, 
'-' normal file, 
'p' for named pipes, 
's' for socket, 
'D' for interprocess communication between client and server (solarus UNIX only)
'l' symbolic link
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try formatted scanf feature which allows you to specify the format of the input that you are expecting.

Comment: do you mean use a regex?